# query user group hide search results

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to change some code so that users with certain group id do not show in search results.

at the moment the code is

```
$query = 'SELECT distinct b.'.$db->nameQuote('id')
        .' FROM '.$db->nameQuote('#__users').' b';
```

I am trying to add something like the following but cannot get it to work.

```
select * from '.$db->quoteName('#__users').' where id not in (select user_id from #__user_usergroup_map where group_id = 8)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This how you can try

```
select * from users u 
where 
not exists
(
  select 1
  from user_group ug
  where 
  u.id = ug.iduser
  AND ug.group_id = 8 
)
```

You need change the table name and field name in the above query as your need.

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de1d8/2)**

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of doing that.

**Method 1: Join**

Join usergroup_map table and then, select all rows that have different group_id that way:

```
SELECT <comma separated fields> from USERS u 
LEFT JOIN USERGROUPS ug ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
WHERE ug.group_id != :group_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

And then -> bind any number to :group_id.

Please keep in mind that above statement will return users that are assigned to :group_id only if they are in another groups as well. (one to many relation).

**Method 2: Subselect**

Already suggested by other users.

**Method 3: Join & Subselect**

The 3rd, and the last option is to use sub-query within join statement, which tends to be the fastest solution in terms of optimalization. Of course, query times may be different depending on the engine you are working with, but it's worth giving a try.

```
SELECT <comma separated fields>
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT g.user_id
    FROM USERGROUPS g 
    WHERE g.group_id != :group_id
  ) ug ON ug.user_id = u.user_id
```

--

In this answer, I assume that you have properly configured database with foreign keys.